# How to upgrade Intel(R) 82567V-2 Gigabit Network Connection Drivers for Windows 7 64?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, network-adapter

### Problem

When I go to Device Manager, under Network adapters I have an Intel(R) 82567V-2 Gigabit Network Connection adapter that has a yellow exclamation point. I am trying to upgrade its drivers but I cannot.

### What I have tried

1. Right click on the adapter/Properties/Driver/Upgrade Driver.../Search Automatically for driver software. I get a message stating that "Windows has determined the driver software for your device is up to date". However the yellow warning is still there.
2. Downloaded the 64 version found in [this](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18713&ProdId=3003&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%207%20(64-bit)*&DownloadType=Drivers) link and run it.

No luck either.

I think that having those errors in that adapter is interfering with the Rooting process for Kindle Fire through SuperOneClick. See my original problem [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17129/superoneclick-not-responding).

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your computer an OEM model? If so, download the proper drivers from the manufacturer's website.

Comment: I built my own PC. My copy of Windows is an OEM System Builder edition. Isn't the link that I have provided on step 2 above where I should be getting the newest drivers?

Comment: Are you sure the 'yellow exclamation point' is related to the driver? Read the device's properties to determine what the **exact** problem is!